# Azure Policy | Tags

Tags: azure

{
"properties": {   ---->  the very first statement errors out and cannot save JSON.

trying to deploy following JSON -

```
{
"properties": {
    "displayName": "Enforce Resource Group Tag Values",
    "policyType": "Custom",
  "mode": "All",
  "parameters": {
    "tagEnv": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Environment",
        "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
```

Comment: Can you share more details about what you are trying to accomplish with the above policy?

Comment: I'm looking to have one tag with more than one possible value.  I'll use this policy to audit resources that are not in compliance.

Comment: so do I copy the code into a policy as is?  Does it need anything else ?  I get this msg "The existing policy has '2' parameter(s) which is greater than the count of parameter(s) '0' in the policy being added. "

Comment: If you do not require any parameters in the new policy definition, you can either remove the 'parameters' section from the new policy JSON or remove the existing policy definition and create a new one using my JSON code.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to have one tag with more than one possible value. I'll use this policy to audit resources that are not in compliance.

Here's an updated policy to enforce tag with multiple possible values.

```json
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "not": {
            "field": "tags['environment']",
            "in": [
              "production",
              "development",
              "testing"
            ]
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "audit"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
```

After applying the policy, it will audit existing resources if the tag does not have three values.

[image]